# Software deployed using WMIC requires restart before launching

Tags: windows, msi, deployment, wmi

I have an MSI I'm attempting to deploy via WMIC.  The MSI install completes without error but I cannot launch the installed application until I reboot the PC.  If I try it pops up momentarily then closes.  As soon as the PC is reboot the application runs fine.

If I install the MSI locally by running it from Windows Explorer, the application works straight away without any reboot required.

If I install the MSI locally from the command line using msiexec the application also starts straight away without any need for PC reboot.

It is only when installed via WMIC that I need to reboot before I can use the installed application.  Here's the command I'm running from the command prompt on the server pushing the install (cmd is running as the administrator account using the the 'runas' command):

```
wmic /node:pc_name product call install true,"" , "c:\PathToMSI\File.msi"
```

How can I work out why the installed application needs a reboot when deployed via WMIC?